# string.Parse equivalent for ModelBindingContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the string equivalent of the following modelbindingcontext int.parse code below?

```
int myint = int.Parse(valueProvider.GetValue("MyId").AttemptedValue);
```

Would like to use `string.Parse` ... but not defined

```
string mystring = string.Parse(valueProvider.GetValue("MyName").AttemptedValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy answer is that `AttemptedValue` is already a string. So I'm not sure what the point of parsing it or calling `ToString()` on it is.

The more correct way of doing both this and your `int` scenario is to use the `ConvertTo()` method of the `ValueProviderResult`.

```
int myInt = valueProvider.GetValue("MyId").ConvertTo(typeof(int));
string myString = valueProvider.GetValue("MyName").ConvertTo(typeof(string));
```